Why would multiple air conditioners fail?
I'm in an apartment with a wall mounted AC unit. Since I moved in months ago, I haven't had a working AC. I have had the AC unit replaced four times. Each replacement unit has had the exact same problem. When I turn on the AC, it will work for a few minutes, producing cool air, and then the fan and compressor will stop while the AC is still on (the LEDs are still on). After the initial turn off, the AC will intermittently make a noise like the compressor is trying to start or the fan is trying to start, but it won't start up again unless I leave it for hours
It seems exceedingly unlikely that I would have four faulty AC units in succession. What could be the cause of this?
If you could help me with this, you'd be my life saver... my maintenance people probably think I'm crazy or sabotaging the AC units.

Have you tried setting the temperature to extremes to see how the AC works

All the ACs have had their own internal temperature setting that I can change on the front of the unit using buttons

@RohitGupta once the AC turns off, no matter what settings I put it will not start again. I can even put it into fan only mode and the fan won't start

@Traveler I actually have had four replacements. At least three of them have been totally new wall mounted units. So the coolant level should be good. (Edited my post to clarify)

Four units unless messing up the install, I would think more power supply than AC problem.  Test the electrics.  Loose receptacle/connections.

Have you had the maintenance people stick around long enough to see the issue?

In an apartment, you probably need a licensed electrician to check the receptacle/wiring.  Four defective AC units would be odd, unless all were the same batch/made on the same day, but even that would be rare.

What's the voltage there? Any indication of voltage trouble in your home?   Are you sure you are using "AC" correctly? Are we referring to the head unit of a split system, or a single-unit in-wall PTAC or window or wall unit?

The common thread to all 4 new units AND the old unit is the power supply.
I would look at that for proper voltage , ground and neutral.  The problem could be the outlet it is plugged into ( especially if the wires are backstabbed.) or the wiring or the breaker.
I had a microwave that would work for a maximum of 90 seconds, then no power. Wait a minute or 2 and the power came back.  The problem was a loose hot wire on the outlet it was plugged into.
